# Limits inside modulus function

Tags: limits

We know limits can be brought inside modulus functions. I mean if we have something of sort $$\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)|$$ then it can also be written as $$\left|\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right|$$There must be really rigorous proofs available but I want to think of it intuitively (*purely in slopes of graph or number line or something of that sort*). The reason being I often forget the the rigorous proofs but if I can visualize something intuitively, I can derive it really easily. Can we prove this intuitively? I hope that the amazing users here can share a bit of their knowledge.

Comment: $g(\lim) = \lim g$ is the definition of continuity. Is modulus a continuous function?

Comment: It’s “just” a statement of the continuity of the absolute value function. Continuity just says that if you wiggle the input a little, the output doesn’t wiggle much either.

Answer (score 0):

If $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$
then

$$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|L|$$

because
$$||f(x)|-|L||\le |f(x)-L|$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=l=|l|$$
does not necessarily imply that

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$$
For example let
$$f(x)=1\text{ if } x>0 $$
and
$$f(x)=-1\text{ if } x<0$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=1$$
but
$$|\lim_0f| \text{ does not exist}$$